# Need advice on database schema for storing complex json

Tags: json, database, postgresql, nosql, database-schema

I cant decide whether to use postgres, cassandra or another nosql

the json collection is like this

```
[{
id:
name: 
year: 
credits: [{id: "", name: "", role: ""}...]
genres: [{id: "", name: ""}...]
seasons: [
         { id:
           name:
           season_number:
           episodes: [
                     {id: "", 
                      name: "", 
                      season_number: "", 
                      episode_number: ""}, 
                      ...] 
         }, 
         ...]
},
...]
```

from above, the collection itself is an array of objects. each object has four nested arrays for values, namely keys `credits`, `genres`, `seasons`, `episodes`.

the full object needs to be read every time because all the fields are needed to be shown on the frontend.

the items in the `episodes` key will be inserted or deleted the most.
they are grouped, split into seasons which is also an array

initial sql table schema was one row per episode, but that creates a lot of json redundancy

its important to have a query that returns the above object in its original structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concur with Laurenz' answer that PostgreSQL would be a better option because of the update/deletes. You can store the data in standard SQL tables and use PostgreSQL JSON support to generate the necessary JSON.

To demonstrate I took your example and created a working example in db_fiddle which you can access here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/81Acp5wdEEaWMMxKfvbUaS/3.

```
create schema test;
create table test.tvshow ( id serial, name text );
create table test.credit ( id serial, show_id integer, name text , role text );
create table test.genre (id serial, name text, show_id integer );
create table test.season ( id serial, name text, season_number text, show_id integer);
create table test.episode ( id serial, name text, season_id integer, episode_number text, show_id integer);

insert into test.tvshow (name) values ('gunsmoke');
insert into test.credit (name, show_id) values ('credits #1', 1);
insert into test.credit (name, show_id) values ('credits #2', 1);
insert into test.credit (name, show_id) values ('credits #3', 1);

insert into test.genre (name, show_id) values ('western', 1);
insert into test.genre (name, show_id) values ('drama', 1);

insert into test.season (name, show_id, season_number) values ('Season 1', 1, '01');
insert into test.season (name, show_id, season_number) values ('Season 2', 1, '02');


insert into test.episode (name, season_id, episode_number, show_id) values ('Episode#1',1, '01', 1);
insert into test.episode (name, season_id, episode_number, show_id) values ('Episode#2',1, '01', 1);
insert into test.episode (name, season_id, episode_number, show_id) values ('Episode#3',1, '01', 1);

insert into test.episode (name, season_id, episode_number, show_id) values ('Episode#1',2, '01', 1);
insert into test.episode (name, season_id, episode_number, show_id) values ('Episode#1',2, '02', 1);
```

Once populated you can execute the following SQL.

```
  SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t, true)))
FROM (
    SELECT name
        ,(
            SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(c)))
            FROM (
                SELECT id
                    ,name
                    ,ROLE
                FROM test.credit
                WHERE test.credit.show_id = test.tvshow.id
                ) c
            ) AS credits
        ,
        --
        (
            SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(g)))
            FROM (
                SELECT id
                    ,name
                FROM test.genre
                WHERE test.genre.show_id = test.tvshow.id
                ) g
            ) AS genres
        ,
        --
        (
            SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(s, true)))
            FROM (
                SELECT id
                    ,name
                    ,season_number
                    ,(
                        SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(e)))
                        FROM (
                            SELECT id
                                ,name
                                ,season_number
                            FROM test.episode
                            WHERE test.episode.show_id = test.tvshow.id
                                AND test.episode.season_id = test.season.id
                            ) e
                        ) AS episodes
                FROM test.season
                WHERE test.season.show_id = test.tvshow.id
                ) s
            ) AS seasons
    --
    FROM test.tvshow
    ) t
```

That will return a with the JSON row for all the shows.

Answer (score 2):

From what you write, it sounds like you will want to update parts of that JSON frequently. In that case, all I can recommend if you want to use PostgreSQL is to *not* store the data as JSON, but to split it up into several tables: `credits`, `genres`, `seasons` and `episodes`.

Sure, this will make the `INSERT` and the `SELECT` of the data somewhat more complicated, as you will have to split up and assemble the JSON, but it will pay off as soon as you try to implement a request like "delete a certain episode" or you want to efficiently search for data using pattern matching.

Also, if you need to retain the whitespace or attribute order in the JSON, this will not work as expected. But that should not matter for JSON data.